# Identify in a dataframe first occurrence of string till another string appear

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new to python and no success in identify the first string of a dataframe respecting a specific rule. I need to change the value of the first called "INVEST" and then reset this count till anothe string appear, which is "WITHDRAW".

This is the dataframe i have got:

| NAME | DATE | TYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME 1 | 01/01/2021 | INVEST | 1000 |
| NAME 1 | 02/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| NAME 1 | 03/01/2021 | INVEST | 501 |
| NAME 1 | 04/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |
| NAME 2 | 05/01/2021 | INVEST | 1000 |
| NAME 2 | 06/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| NAME 2 | 07/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |
| NAME 1 | 08/01/2021 | INVEST | 1000 |
| NAME 1 | 11/01/2021 | INVEST | 1000 |
| NAME 1 | 12/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| NAME 1 | 09/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| NAME 1 | 10/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |
| NAME 1 | 13/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |

And this is how I want to be:

| NAME | DATE | TYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME 1 | 01/01/2021 | FIRST INVEST | 1000 |
| NAME 1 | 02/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| NAME 1 | 03/01/2021 | INVEST | 501 |
| NAME 1 | 04/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |
| NAME 2 | 05/01/2021 | FIRST INVEST | 1000 |
| NAME 2 | 06/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| NAME 2 | 07/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |
| NAME 1 | 08/01/2021 | FIRST INVEST | 1000 |
| NAME 1 | 11/01/2021 | INVEST | 1000 |
| NAME 1 | 12/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| NAME 1 | 09/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| NAME 1 | 10/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |
| NAME 1 | 13/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |

I trying in many ways how to do that, but it seems impossible to me =(

Can anyone please save my life?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) in a filter to check whether the previous value of an `INVEST` type is not `INVEST`, then rename to `FIRST INVEST` where `True`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "01/01/2021", "TYPE": "INVEST", "VALUE": 1000 }, { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "02/01/2021", "TYPE": "INVEST", "VALUE": 500 }, { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "03/01/2021", "TYPE": "INVEST", "VALUE": 501 }, { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "04/01/2021", "TYPE": "WITHDRAW", "VALUE": 1500 }, { "NAME": "NAME 2", "DATE": "05/01/2021", "TYPE": "INVEST", "VALUE": 1000 }, { "NAME": "NAME 2", "DATE": "06/01/2021", "TYPE": "INVEST", "VALUE": 500 }, { "NAME": "NAME 2", "DATE": "07/01/2021", "TYPE": "WITHDRAW", "VALUE": 1500 }, { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "08/01/2021", "TYPE": "INVEST", "VALUE": 1000 }, { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "11/01/2021", "TYPE": "INVEST", "VALUE": 1000 }, { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "12/01/2021", "TYPE": "INVEST", "VALUE": 500 }, { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "09/01/2021", "TYPE": "INVEST", "VALUE": 500 }, { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "10/01/2021", "TYPE": "WITHDRAW", "VALUE": 1500 }, { "NAME": "NAME 1", "DATE": "13/01/2021", "TYPE": "WITHDRAW", "VALUE": 1500 } ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.loc[(df['TYPE'].shift(periods=1) != 'INVEST') & (df['TYPE'] == 'INVEST'), 'TYPE'] = 'FIRST INVEST'
```

Result:

|  | NAME | DATE | TYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NAME 1 | 01/01/2021 | FIRST INVEST | 1000 |
| 1 | NAME 1 | 02/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| 2 | NAME 1 | 03/01/2021 | INVEST | 501 |
| 3 | NAME 1 | 04/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |
| 4 | NAME 2 | 05/01/2021 | FIRST INVEST | 1000 |
| 5 | NAME 2 | 06/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| 6 | NAME 2 | 07/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |
| 7 | NAME 1 | 08/01/2021 | FIRST INVEST | 1000 |
| 8 | NAME 1 | 11/01/2021 | INVEST | 1000 |
| 9 | NAME 1 | 12/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| 10 | NAME 1 | 09/01/2021 | INVEST | 500 |
| 11 | NAME 1 | 10/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |
| 12 | NAME 1 | 13/01/2021 | WITHDRAW | 1500 |